# how to judge imgs is all loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a project to know the imgs' height when the document is loading,but at first i got the height is zero  So is there any tips to know whether the imgs is already loaded? I tried to use $.deferred inside jQuery; here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
  var imgdefereds = [];

  $('img').each(function() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    $(this).bind('load', function() {
      dfd.resolve();
    }).bind('error', function() {
      //error callback
    })

    if (this.complete) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.resolve();
      }, 1000);
    }
    imgdefereds.push(dfd.promise());
  })

  $.when.apply(null, imgdefereds).done(function() {
    console.log('complete');
  });
})
```

It didn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you checking for img's height ? `$('img').height()` will return the computed height (can be zero if e.g display is none or if `img`'s height attribute is 0) `img.height` will return the `height` property (can be zero if `height` attribute is 0), `img.naturalHeight` will return the real height of the media.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("img").one("load", function() {
  // do stuff
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```